# Google Secret Manager Permission Denied with Firebase Function

Tags: python, firebase, google-secret-manager

I'm writing a firebase function in Python that need to access a token stored in Secrets Manager. **When the app is initialized locally using the firebase credentials from the same project, I was able to fetch the token correctly with no error, but when it's deployed to said project on Firebase, I'm getting a permission denied error**:

```
REQUEST ERROR: 403 Permission 'secretmanager.versions.access' denied for resource
'projects/some_project_id/secrets/some_token_name/versions/latest' (or it may not exist).
```

Code here:

```py
def _get_token():
    # Initialize the Secret Manager client
    client = secretmanager.SecretManagerServiceClient()
    # Build the secret version path
    secret_name = f"projects/some_project_id/secrets/some_token_name/versions/latest"
    # Access the secret
    response = client.access_secret_version(request={"name": secret_name})
    payload = response.payload.data.decode("UTF-8")
    return payload
```

Accessor:
{project_name}@appspot.gserviceaccount.com (inherited role)

Answer (score 0):

Firebase now support GCP secrets directly.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env?gen=2nd

```
from firebase_functions import https_fn
from firebase_functions.params import SecretParam

DISCORD_API_KEY = SecretParam('DISCORD_API_KEY');

@https_fn.on_request(secrets=[DISCORD_API_KEY])
def post_to_discord(req):
    api_key = DISCORD_API_KEY.value
```